# How servlet controller know which method to use?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm new to servlet. I have a question that when you give a request , how do servlet controller know which function inside it should it use? (i.e. there are two function ,1. get export a report file and 2. display it only)

I know that there need to be a jsp with baseurl link to it with ajax but I have no idea why it knows to choose which function

Comment: The HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT etc.) and the servlet mapping in `web.xml` or other configuration determine which method is called for which URL.

Comment: That question is almost as vague as it can be. Please read [ask] and show some code/example of what you mean. Servlets provide the method `service()` which is called and in that method `HttpServlet` will check the request method type (GET, POST etc.) and call the appropriate method. From there it depends on which servlet you're using, i.e. they could operate based on the url being called, on some parameters etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you're new to Servlet, I would suggest, don't confuse yourself with `AJAX` and all other things -- How do you eat an elephant? of course, one bite at a time. So, Read [Servlet Lifecycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html), try to understand that first; then go bit by bit from there.